# Unable to insert values in SQLite3 database using JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite

I have the following JDBC code , in which I am not getting any error, but unfortunately the data is not being added to the database. The code that I am using is :

```
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:../../clientDb.db");
      c.setAutoCommit(false);

      String expenseUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      expenseUUID = expenseUUID.replaceAll("-", "");

      String sqlQuery = "insert into expense (expenseUUID , user_id,expense_description, 
                        total_amount, place, per_exp_flag, category " +
                        ",creation_date ) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";


         ps = c.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);

            ps.setString(1, expenseUUID);
            ps.setInt(2, user_id);
            ps.setString(3, description);
            ps.setInt(4, total_amount);
            ps.setString(5, place);
            ps.setInt(6, 1);
            ps.setInt(7, category);
            ps.setString(8, creation_date);


        int result =  ps.executeUpdate();

        if(result == 1){

              b = true;

         }
```

What is the error ? When I tried using select statement , I got the result in the result set, But why is it not inserting anything? I am getting '1' in

```
      int result =  ps.executeUpdate();
```

What is possibly the error? I am using SQLite3 as back-end database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `c.setAutoCommit(false);` so your INSERT won't actually be written to the database until you `c.commit();`. Add that statement after the `ps.executeUpdate()`.